# is it possible to make a master layout in android?

Tags: android

in an android application is it possible to create a master layout? that is that has a toolbar or actionBar and a drawerlayout for registered users and this master layout can load in part of it what is in other layout when clic an option of a menu, and other master layout similar that has also a toolbar and a drawerlayout but with different options for users not registered? how can be made and what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create different layouts in android studio without issue.`SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);`If you see that line of code you could in theory have an if statement that sets the content view based on membership and then redirects them to the right layout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have your two different master layout and load it if condition satisfies.

Consider, you having two different master layout,

**1. for_registered_users.xml**

**2. for_non_registered_users.xml**

In you onCreate method, you can set layout content view like this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(registeredUsers){
    setContentView(R.layout.for_registered_users);
    }else{
    setContentView(R.layout.for_non_registered_users);
    }
}
```